# How does Groupon and Fab's push notifications show up as soon as I turn on my phone?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

It seems as soon as I unlock my iPhone in the morning Groupon's notifications show up on the top of my notification tray. This can happen anywhere between 8-10am, so I was wondering how are they able to do this.